# Parsing Javascript Functions from text file

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I guess this is kinda a crazy out there question as I haven't found much in terms of references to it but maybe I've just been looking in the wrong place. What I'm setting out to do is to take my entire Javascript program (that exists in a single file) and I want to store it in the equivalent of a string.

I want to then take a secondary program that reads that string that contains my javascript code and execute it as if it was a normal javascript file. For example sets of code I have this as a structure of the code that would be in the string

```
var adminRole;
var account;
var color;
function sayHello() {
    console.log('hello');
};
sayHello()
```

If that code was stored in a plain text file. Is there any simple way to then turn it all into javascript code and evaluate it like you normally would?

Comment: Rather than doing something like `eval(...)`, would you be able to simply `import`/`require` the file?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). EDIT: But be aware of this: "Warning: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use eval()." (from the linked website)

Comment: the goal is to not have this code exist as a file whatsoever, which means I cannot really import / require it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: I feel so dumb... I had no idea I could eval the entire code base. Thank you so much lema